# Why Thevenin's theorem is being violated?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

[image]

in the given picture we need to find the current flowing through the 3 ohm resistor. Applying KVL we can find the current as 4 amps but if we thevenise the circuit at terminal a-b then the current we have found is not 4 amps. So the question is why thevenin's theorem is not working in this case? plz help me out.

Comment: Define your acronyms, such as KVL.

Comment: This question is too vague. You could show your work and then ask why the Thevenin method doesn't agree with the Kirchoff laws method... but you need to show your work.

Comment: DanielSank: KVL is short for "Kirchoff's Voltage Law". @Abir: as DanielSank says you need to show us your working. As a hint, note that the diamond shaped voltage source is a dependent voltage source, and the usual Thevenin procedure (short voltage sources, open current sources) applies to independent sources.  Is this something that you perhaps overlooked?

Answer (score 2):

As long as the circuit is [linear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_circuit) you should be able to find a Thevenin equivalent circuit.

The next thing to note is that you usually find the equivalent Thevenin circuit for a real circuit in order to evaluate (more easily) what happens in the external circuit which in your case is the $3 \; \Omega$ (load) resistor connected between nodes $a$ and $b$.
So knowing the Thevenin equivalent circuit you can find for the $3 \; \Omega$ resistor the potential difference across it, the current passing through it and the power dissipated in it.
In general you cannot find the power dissipated in the real circuit for which you have found the Thevenin equivalent using the Thevenin equivalent circuit even though you can find the power dissipated in the load resistor.

I have include the preamble because the Thevenin equivalent for your circuit is rather unusual but remember the Thevenin equivalent circuit is found to make working out the sums easier.

---

Here is the Thevenin equivalent circuit:

[image]

The minus sign might astonish you but remember the aim of a Thevenin equivalent circuit if to relatively easily find out things about the load and when you have circuits with dependent sources then occasionally a negative resistance does turn up.
With the negative resistance the conventional current flows from a low potential to a higher potential.

They say that "the proof of the pudding is in the eating" so see is this Thevenin equivalent circuit does correctly predict the voltages and current for a load resistor of $3 \; \Omega$, an open circuit across nodes $ab$, a short circuit across nodes $ab$ and any other resistance you care to chose but do include $+8 \; \Omega\;$ :-).

You will note that for this circuit as you increase the load resistor the current also increases.

---

There are components which do exhibit a negative small signal / differential / incremental resistance, for example the [tunnel diode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunnel_diode).